# Python __file__ variable returns 'encoding error'

Tags: python, encoding, path, cyrillic

So my script is in the folder which contains cyrillic symbols in the path and the `__file__`

variabale returns "encoding error" instead of a real path.

Adding the following line doesnt help

`# -*- coding: cp1252 -*-`

What should I do?

Version of python 3.3

Comment: Could you please provide the part where you deal with `__file__` ?
An exception is raised? Or `__file__` variable contents are equal to `encoding error` ?

Comment: I am just trying to print it, thats all, like `print(__file__)`

Comment: Any particular reason to use `cp1252` and not the default `utf-8` encoding of that file?

Comment: The script name is in utf8, but the path to it contains cyrillic symols, the clients use the folders with their specific names. Also, if I print the globals() there is `'__file__': '<encoding error>'`

Comment: No exception is raised, the content of variable is equal to `<encoding error>`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this answers your question, but...

In python3 the `__file__` holds the current running script and path as a `str`.  *nix systems use binary for filenames and have no preference for a particular encoding.  When you use `__file__` the system will attempt to take the binary string and encode it into a string using the default encoding system.  I'm wondering if maybe your filenames are in cp1252 and python is trying to interpret it as utf8.

Python may follow the convention outlined here when encoding `__file__`:  http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.getfilesystemencoding

You didn't state what OS you're using, though...